# how to change URLs in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

I have the next URL: http://www.xxxx.xx/8-2/noticias/ in Wordpress where noticias is the category which I want, but I see a 8-2 there, how can I remove this?. About permanent links I have this:

Post name:
http://www.axpertia.es/example-page/ I have tested more things but nothing, could you advice me something?.

Thanks so much and regards

Answer (score 0):

change permalink in wordpress:

some times it will not work on local server...

Comment: I have done it and it doesn't work.I don't work in local, I do it in real server

Comment: which type of server you are using windows or linux ?

Comment: permalinks works fine if rewrite_module is enabled on your server, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to setting->Permalinks->Select Post Name

Answer (score 0):

Enable  `rewrite_module` in your apache and this will work.

To see how to do this :  [How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)